# Printing results in reverse order from raw_input in python

Tags: python, raw-input

When using `raw_input` in a loop, until a certain character is typed (say `'a'`), how can I print all the inputs before that, in reverse order, without storing the inputs in a data structure?

Using a string is simple:

```
def foo():

    x = raw_input("Enter character: ")
    string = ""
    while not (str(x) == "a"):
        string = str(x) + "\n" + string
        x = raw_input("Enter character: ")
    print string.strip()
```

but how could I do the same without a string?

Comment: *without storing the inputs in a data structure*, why is that? is this a homework?

Comment: Why did you edit almost the entire question content away?

Comment: `without storing the inputs in a data structure` do you even know what a data structure is?

Answer (score 5):

This is not a practical approach, but since you asked for it:

```
def getchar():
    char = raw_input("Enter character: ")
    if char != 'a':
        getchar()
        print char

getchar()
```

Of course this only means that I'm using "hidden" data structures, the local namespace and the call stack.

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the results in *some* data structure.  Instead of a string, however, you could store each input in a list and avoid all the string concatenation:

```
l = []
x = raw_input("Enter character: ")
while not (str(x) == 'a'):
    l.append(x)
    x = raw_input("Enter character: ")

print '\n'.join(l[::-1])
```